# HTML Form Radio Buttons and Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a form in which if a radio button is selected, some checkboxes associated with it open up and the user must select at least one of the checkboxes under that radio button before submitting the form. For example refer to the codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJKPRK.  This is based on a dogs/cats tutorial I saw.

Here, item propagation is used to make all child items required:

```
var FormStuff = {

init: function() {
    this.applyConditionalRequired();
    this.bindUIActions();
  },

  bindUIActions: function() {
    $("input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox']").on("change", this.applyConditionalRequired);
  },


  applyConditionalRequired: function() {


$(".require-if-active").each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  if ($(el.data("require-pair")).is(":checked")) {

    el.prop("required", true);
  } else {
    el.prop("required", false);
  }
});
},   
};
FormStuff.init();
```

Here at least 1 radio button needs to be selected and if ClassB or ClassC is selected, I want that the user should select at least one checkbox under that particular class. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`.length` gives you the count of elements in your selection. `$('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked').length > 0` tells you whether or not at least 1 Checkbox has been checked. Just add classes to your selector as desired.